# Unable to load the requested file in home.php

Tags: javascript, php, web

I'm having problems getting the home page.

When I open the page I get this error:

Invalid Attempt
Unable to load the requested file: home.php

This is the page: 
http://bonoboapp.es/

and code of home.php

```
<?php

class Home extends Front_Controller 
{

    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Home_model');

    }

    function index() 
    {

        $data['seo_title'] = 'Bonobo App';
        $data['seo_description'] = 'Seo descrip';
        $data['seo_keyword'] = 'Bonobo App';

        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('text');
        $data['testimonials'] = $this->Home_model->get_testimonials($limit = 3);
        $data = $this->Home_model->get_recently_trip_list($limit = 10, $data);
        $data['advertisement_image'] = $this->Home_model->getad_image();
        $data['top_rating'] = $this->Home_model->top_ratinguser();


        $this->load->view('home', $data);
    }

    function feedbacks($last_segment)
    {
        $data['seo_title'] = 'Comentarios del usuario';
        $data['seo_description'] = 'Todos los comentarios de los usuarios';
        $data['seo_keyword'] = 'Comentarios del usuario';  
        $data['feedbacks'] = $this->Home_model->get_feedbacks($last_segment);
        $get_user_id = $data['feedbacks']; 

        if(empty($get_user_id)){
           $this->load->view('nofeedbacks',$data);
        }       
          $data['feedback_user'] = $this->Home_model->get_feedbackuser($last_segment); 
          $data['last_segment'] = $last_segment;

          if($get_user_id !=''){
           $this->load->view('nofeedbacks',$data);
        }

    }

    function changeLanguage() {

        $key = $this->input->post('key');        
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('lanCode');
        if($this->aleray_add_lang != ""){

            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', lang('change_language_option'));
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata(array(
            'lanCode' => $key
        ));

        $lanCode = $this->session->userdata('lanCode');
        //print_r($lanCode);die;

        if($lanCode){

            die(json_encode(array('result'=>true)));            
        }else{

            die(json_encode(array('result'=>false)));  
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I don't understand what's wrong, could you helpme please.

I'm using PHP version 7.2.

The database it's correct.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using CodeIgniter? That's pretty relevant information for us to have.

Comment: Yes, i use CodeIgniter